# Web Development Displaying Local Files

Tags: javascript, filereader

Based on research, I've found tutorials, [such as this one from Eric Bidelman](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), that go into FileReader usage. Instead of local files, these tutorials use files provided by the user. Modifying these examples to try and display local files were not successful.

After some research I've found that most browsers by default do not allow access to local files [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764583/can-i-use-javascripts-filereader-on-a-local-file-if-i-know-the-location). Some recommend using unsafe modes for testing, but that's not what I'm looking for as that would apply to only my testing [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745568/filereader-api-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-from-local-file).

Currently I allow the download of log files. My goal here with FileReader was to provide a way to view the files as well. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm coming up with blanks and have almost resigned to only allowing downloads instead of adding viewing. The following is example code of local file reading. This code fails since 'logpath' is not of type blob. I believe my question doesn't really require code, but I provided an example anyway.

**HTML Code**

```
<select name="loglist" id="loglist" onchange="run()" size="2">
    <option>stack1.log</option>
    <option>stack2.log</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function run() {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    log = document.getElementById( "loglist" ).value;
    var logdir = "/var/log/";
    var logpath = logdir.concat(log);

    reader.onload = function() {
        logtext = reader.result;
        alert(logtext);
    }
    reader.readAsText(logpath);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for JavaScript, embedded in a webpage, to access files on the user's local system other than through the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) when **the user selects the file using a file input**. It is not possible for the page to supply the file name to be opened.

```js
var inp = document.querySelector("input");
inp.addEventListener("change", show);

function show(e) {
  var f = this.files[0];
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.addEventListener("load", display);
  r.readAsText(f);

  function display(e) {
    document.body.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(
        e.target.result
      )
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input">
```